# My exists function says the file exists, but winapi functions say it does not

Tags: image, file, winapi

I copied [code that's supposed to change desktop wallpaper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8438067/607407). I have this constant in my program:

```
const char * image_name = "button_out.gif";
```

Later, I write the image on disk using `Magick++`:

```
image.write(image_name);
```

The image appears in program's *working directory*. If I run the program directly from explorer the working directory equals the program location.

[image: image and the image generator]

Because the code prints the `0x80070002 - File not found` error I added a exist function in the beginning:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
bool exists(const char* name) {
  struct stat buffer;   
  return (stat (name, &buffer) == 0); 
}
void  SetWallpaper(LPCWSTR file){
  if(!exists((const char* )file)) {
    wcout << "The file "<<file<<" does not exist!" << endl;  
  return;
  ... actually try to set a wallpaper ...
}
```

The error is not printed however and the code proceeds.

Now the question is:

1. Does my exist function work properly?
2. Where does windows look for that image?

Full code to [set a Magick++ generated image as background](http://pastebin.com/vvNh0iYr) in case I have missed something relevant in this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem 1: String Conversions

Your primary problem is that you are attempting to use `LPCWSTR` (a `const wchar_t *`) and `const char *` interchangeably. I see a number of issues in your source, in particular:

- You start with `const char * image_name`.
- You then cast it to a `LPCWSTR` to pass to `SetWallpaper`. This basically guarantees that `SetWallpaper` will fail, as `desktop->SetWallpaper` is not able to handle non wide-character strings.
- You then cast it back to a `const char *` to pass to `stat()` via `exists()`. This *should* work in your situation (since the original string really is a `char *`) but isn't *correct* because your string parameter to `SetWallpaper` is *supposedly* a proper `LPCWSTR`.

You need to pick a string format (wide-character vs. what Windows terms "ANSI") and stick to that format, using consistent APIs throughout.

The easiest option is probably just to leave most of your code untouched, but modify `SetWallpaper` to take a `const char *` and convert to a wide-character string when needed (for this you can use [`mbstowcs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy.aspx)). So, for example:

```
void  SetWallpaper(const char * file){  // <- Use a const char* parameter.
   ...

   // Convert to a wide-character string to pass to COM: 
   wchar_t wcfile[MAX_PATH + 1];
   mbstowcs(wcfile, file, sizeof(wcfile) / sizeof(wchar_t));

   // Pass the converted wide-character string:
   desktop->SetWallpaper(wcfile, 0);

   ...
}
```

The other option would be to use wide-character strings throughout, i.e.:

- `LPCWSTR image_name = L"button_out.gif";`
- Modify `exists()` to take a `LPCWSTR` and use [`_wstat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28VS.71%29.aspx) instead.
- Use wide-character versions of all other API functions.

However, I am unsure how that would interact with the ImageMagick API, which may not have wide-character support. So it's up to you. Choose whatever approach is the easiest to implement but make sure you are consistent. The general rule is **do not cast between `LPCWSTR` and `const char *`**; if you are ever in a situation where you need to change one to the other, you cannot cast, you *must* convert (via `mbstowcs` or `wcstombs`).

#### Problem 2: SetWallpaper default directory is not current working directory

At this point, your string usage will be consistent. Now that you have that problem ironed out, if `SetWallpaper` fails while `exists()` does not, then `SetWallpaper` is not looking where you think it is. As you discovered in your comment, `SetWallpaper` looks in the desktop by default. In this case, while I have not tested it, you may be able to work around this by passing an *absolute path* to `SetWallpaper`. For this, you can use [`GetFullPathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine the absolute file name given your relative path. Remember to be consistent with your string types, though.

Also, if `stat()` continues to fail, then *that* problem is either that your working directory is not what you think it is, or your filename is not what you think it is. To that end you will want to perform the following tests:

- Print the current working directory at the point you check for the files existence, verify it is correct.
- Print the filename when you check for its existence, verify it is correct.

You should be good to go once you work all the above issues out.

Comment: But the guy in the question I used is doing it and says it works... :( But thanks, I'll try to find a way to convert the data properly.

Comment: @TomášZato I added a bit about how to convert. The guy in the question you used is *not* doing what you are doing. The problem is that you are passing a wide-character string to `stat`. It's a problem with how you call your `exists()` function, not your wallpaper setting.

Comment: Thank you. However, it still does not work. I also tried to add the check *before* the `SetWallpaper` call where the filename is `const char*` and it still does not trown the error. Which I find correct since the file *is* there. There must be another problem. I'll use procmon to see where is the program looking for the file.

Comment: @TomášZato I have taken a look at your code and updated the answer again. This is the best advice I have to offer.

Comment: Well well well, finally I'm getting something... Thank you very much for fixing all the errors. Now I can see the [system looks in `Desktop` for the file](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eAMp4.png). Add this to the answer since you deserve most of the credit for finding out.

Comment: @TomášZato Good catch on that, too. I've added it to the answer. You could also try passing an absolute path to `SetWallpaper`. I haven't tested it but it may be a workaround for `SetWallpaper`s default directory not being the same as the current working directory.

Comment: ALWAYS use absolute paths, NEVER use relative paths.